# Find Black Squares in Image ( matlab )

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

i have hundreds of paper-forms and i want to automatically read this forms. 
The first step would be to calibrate the scanned paper. ( find the coordinates of the 4 squares )

But i don't know how to do it in matlab :(

here is the picture : 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/wR463.png]

Comment: What have you tried to do or do you have an idea how you would do this in <random image processing framework>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532078/how-can-i-detect-registration-markers-on-paper-using-opencv) using OpenCV. For detecting the paper sheet itself, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Havard,

this solution helped me.
This is what i did :

```
I = imread('inv-small.png');
BW = edge(I,'canny',0.3);
imshow(BW);
C = corner(BW,4);
imshow(I);
hold on
plot(C(:,1), C(:,2), 'r*');
hold off
```

results in : 
[image]

Comment: Did you try it when the inner part of the document is not blurred?

Comment: If the input image has colors in it, you could e.g. do this: BW = im2bw(I,level), where level is some threshold like Otsu's: level = graythresh(I);