# Detecting Shape, Colour and Orientation in OpenCV using Webcam

Tags: python, opencv, colors, orientation, shapes

I want to use OpenCV to detect 3 basic shapes (arrow , cross , T-shape) and classify them.

The arrows will have to be classified by colour and orientation(left facing/right facing). The crosses will just have to be detected. I found [this Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv) which is almost what I need. I just have to add colour and orientation detection to it.

A simple if/else if structure will be the easiest for me to implement, since the onboard computer will be communicating to the drive controller using a virtual serial port. That way, I can send simple commands to the drive controller based on the detected shape.

I will be using a webcam as image source , so if you can give a nudge in the right direction for using it, it would help a lot.

All help is appreciated. I want to do this for an autonomous robot with image processing. I am new to OpenCV so please help me out. Both Python and C++ examples are welcome, but Python is more suitable since my onboard computer will run Linux. C++ examples are great too!

Comment: This is quite generic. Can you be more specific as to what your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem requires a *very* extensive answer, but here's an outline of one possible approach:

- If the shape can move, you need to detect it. If you have a static single-color background, this is easily done with [thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_%28image_processing%29). [Here's an OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) on that.
- Next, you need to [classify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_in_machine_learning) the shape. One of the simplest classifiers is the [K-NN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm). [Here's a tutorial](http://www.aishack.in/2010/10/k-nearest-neighbors-in-opencv/)
- Finally, you need to react on the classification output. Since you're using a robot, if you don't know how to interface with it, you're better served by asking a separate question for that.