# Opencv blob detection and vectorization

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, blob

I have a piece of flat material which has seen pieces taken off (convex pieces) and I would like to have what's left of it vectorized.

For example this picture  http://www.laser-cutting.com/images/Coreplast_med.jpg

In this image's case I would like the blob of the circle and of the star identified as not part of the material anymore, their contours and the contour of the image vectorized as to be left only with what's left of the material (forget the handwriting).
Getting the contours is no problem with the cvCanny but how do I then vectoriz the contours? Is there a way to identify the blobs?

Any idea on how to proceed? I've read many blob-related questions but none helped me.

Thanks

Comment: "convex pieces", the star is definitely not convex.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [`cvFindContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#int%20cvFindContours%28CvArr*%20image,%20CvMemStorage*%20storage,%20CvSeq**%20first_contour,%20int%20header_size,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20CvPoint%20offset%29) does what you want... ?

Comment: In simple words, do you want to find that objects in image ? Or what do you mean by "vectorize" them?

Answer (score 0):

In case you know what your shapes will look like, you could try this:
[How to detect simple geometric shapes using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv)

Also cvFindContours as Samuel Audet said should be good for the vectorization :
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

> **contours** – Detected contours. Each contour is stored as a **vector of points**.

From there you can play around with your points and make whatever 2D representation/processing you want.