# Detection of symmetries in Python

Tags: python, detection, symmetry

I want to detect symmetries (rotation, translation, etc) of a simple figure or a shape in a image. That is, if I find one symmetry I want to replicate my original figure with it.

Are there any function or module?
I have thought in python-opencv, but I did not find nothing.

Comment: What are your purposes here? If you're just interested in detecting the rotation of highly similar images, you of course would only need to do a fraction of the work...

Comment: First I want resolve a simple problem, after, I will do problems more difficult in my test

Comment: Can you give an example of a shape in python.

Answer (score 1):

Let me just throw some packages at you: [OpenCV for Python Cookbook](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html) might be a good start. A [search for "opencv" on the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=opencv&submit=search) yields several bindings of OpenCV for Python.

Concerning the detection of symmetries: The answer to question *[how to detect simple geometric shapes using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv)* might be a good start. After you find similar objects, check their orientation. Replacing then should be a piece of cake.