# How to find arcs or open curves in a line drawing?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

I'm facing a problem which I thought was simple but now it's tearing up my scalp.

Given a line drawing, is it possible to find the number of arcs or curves in the drawing? If possible at all, what would be the best way to go about this?

*Example:*

[image: line drawing with two curves]

The above image has two curves but I have been trying all sorts of algorithms to locate them with no success. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please choose a language.

Comment: Here's an example using OpenCV : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv

Comment: Is the goal to find the two curves or to eliminate the closed shapes?

Comment: what assumptions can be made about the input image?  Will it only have curves and closed shapes as in the example above or can it be a wild jumble of shapes and lines and curves?

Comment: You might have some success with edge detection and then following those edges checking gradients for smooth changes in those gradients and then ensuring that the edges don't close?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following issue:

We can take any point on the drawing and then start moving to any direction (in terms of - take second drawing point, third, fourth, …) After each step we check: if we already have been in this point or not.

If yes – the drawing is closed.

If there are no more points to check – the drawing is not closed.