# Detecting (and locating) predefined shapes in image in Java

Tags: java, opencv, shapes, detection

Given an image and a set of predefined unique shapes with a certain colour (e.g. red triangle, green circle, green triangle, yellow square, ...). The image contains some of these shapes at random locations. I have the predefined shapes available as an image-file for each shape if needed.

How can I detect/recognise all of these shapes and return their location in some way, in Java?

OpenCV seems to be a common solution for Python, but I can't find any helpful example/tutorial for Java. I really don't know where to start. Hints/examples much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but a python version similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv/11427501#11427501

Comment: That question is about detecting regular shapes. I also want to detect irregular, predefined shapes. As long as have a quality picture of the shape, my program should be able to detect it.