# How to make Improve shape detection in video stream

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to make a shape detection program that will detect shapes on the ground while flying on an RC aircraft. The problem is that the program is not very accurate. It will find a shape once in a while, but not consistently. I've tried HSV filtering and Canny thresholding, but they don't seem to be working the way I'm using them. Is there any way to improve or is my method totally off?

I've included images of the stuff I've been testing this on.

Shapes should be outlined on this window -->

[image]

Thresholded image is seen in this window -->

[image]

The code I've been messing with is included right here

```
 //include section
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
using namespace cv;

//finds the angles for shape detection Status: Good to go
double angle( CvPoint* pt1, CvPoint* pt2, CvPoint* pt0 );

//This is for color filtering Status: Doesn't Work Yet
IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* imgHSV);

// flag definitions 1: HSV color filtering; 2: Canny Edge Detect; 3: HSV Filter with canny filtering;
////Change these values to get what you need
int flag = 1;


//These values change the HSV filtering values. 
int Hue_Min = 112;
int Hue_Max = 251;

int Saturation_Min = 0;
int Saturation_Max = 256;

int Value_Min = 38;
int Value_Max = 218;


int main()
{
    //Make the windows
    cvNamedWindow("Thresholded",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cvNamedWindow("Tracked",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cvNamedWindow("Original",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

    //Gets stuff from camera
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

    //This variable will hold all the frames. It will hold only one frame on each iteration of the loop. 
    IplImage* frame;

    while(1)
    {
        //Gets Frame from camera
        std::cout << "frame capture\n";
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        std::cout << "Check\n";

        //puts the original image in the window
        cvShowImage("Original",frame);

        std::cout << "declare imgGrayScale\n";
        IplImage* imgGrayScale;
        std::cout << "check\n";

        //Use the Pyramid thing rob has been working on here
            //
        //cvSmooth( frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 5 );



        if(flag ==1){
        //Filter unwanted colors out
            std::cout << "HSV Flag Active\n";
            std::cout << "HSV Color Filter\n";
            imgGrayScale = GetThresholdedImage(frame);
            std::cout << "Check\n";
        }

        if(flag ==2)
        {
            std::cout << "Grayscale HSV Flag Active\n";
          //Making a single channel matrix so that edge detection can work properly 
            std::cout << "Grayscale Image\n";
            imgGrayScale = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 1);
                 cvCvtColor(frame,imgGrayScale,CV_BGR2GRAY);
            std::cout << "Check\n";




        // This thresholds the grayscale image to be tested on
        std::cout << "Canny Threshold Image\n";
            //cvThreshold(imgGrayScale,imgGrayScale,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);  
            cvCanny( imgGrayScale, imgGrayScale, 100, 100, 3 );
        std::cout << "Check\n";
        }
        if(flag == 3)
        {
            std::cout << "HSV Canny Flag Active\n";
            std::cout << "HSV Color Filter\n";
            imgGrayScale = GetThresholdedImage(frame);
            std::cout << "Check\n";
            std::cout << "Canny Threshold Image\n";
            //cvThreshold(imgGrayScale,imgGrayScale,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);  
            cvCanny( imgGrayScale, imgGrayScale, 100, 100, 3 );
            std::cout << "Check\n";

        }

        std::cout << "Contour Allocation\n";
            CvSeq* contours;  //hold the pointer to a contour in the memory block
            CvSeq* result;   //hold sequence of points of a contour
            CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0); //storage area for all contours

        std::cout << "Check\n";

        std::cout << "Find Contours\n";
            //finding all contours in the image
            cvFindContours(imgGrayScale, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
        std::cout << "Check\n";
            while(contours){

                //obtain a sequence of points of contour, pointed by the variable 'contour'
                result = cvApproxPoly(contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0);


                //Triangle Detection 
                 //if there are 3  vertices  in the contour(It should be a triangle)
                if(result->total==3 )
                    {
                        //iterating through each point
                        CvPoint *pt[3];
                        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                        pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
                        }

                        //This If Statement ensures that the edges are sufficiently large enough to be detected
                        if(abs(pt[1]->x - pt[0]->x)>10 && abs(pt[1]->x - pt[2]->x)>10 && abs(pt[2]->x - pt[0]->x)>10){
                            //////////drawing lines around the triangle
                            cvLine(frame, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
                            cvLine(frame, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
                            cvLine(frame, *pt[2], *pt[0], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
                            std::cout << "\nTriangle\n";
                        }
                    }

                //Rectangle detection
                    //if there are 4 vertices in the contour(It should be a quadrilateral)
                else if(result->total==4 )
                {
                        //iterating through each point
                        CvPoint *pt[4];
                        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                        pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
                        }

                //finding angles
                double firstAngle = acos(angle( pt[0],pt[2],pt[1] ));
                double secondAngle = acos(angle(pt[1],pt[3],pt[2]));
                double thirdAngle = acos(angle(pt[1],pt[3],pt[2]));
                double fourthAngle = acos(angle(pt[0],pt[2],pt[3]));

                //This If Statement Ensures that the edges are sufficiently large
                    if(abs(pt[1]->x - pt[0]->x)>10 && abs(pt[1]->x - pt[2]->x)>10 && abs(pt[2]->x - pt[3]->x)>10 && abs(pt[3]->x - pt[0]->x)>10){

                        //This if statement checks the angles to see if its a rectangle or not (90 angles with 10% uncertainty)
                        if(firstAngle <= 1.884 && firstAngle >= 1.308 && secondAngle <= 1.884 && secondAngle >= 1.308 && thirdAngle <= 1.884 && thirdAngle >= 1.308 && fourthAngle <= 1.884 && fourthAngle >= 1.308 )
                            {
                                //drawing lines around the quadrilateral
                                cvLine(frame, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
                                cvLine(frame, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
                                cvLine(frame, *pt[2], *pt[3], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
                                cvLine(frame, *pt[3], *pt[0], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);

                                std::cout << "\nsquare\n" ;
                                //cout << firstAngle; //Uncomment this to get the angles that its detecting. 
                            }
                    }
                }
                contours = contours->h_next;

            }



          //Put the images in the frame
            cvShowImage("Tracked",frame);
            cvShowImage("Thresholded",imgGrayScale);



            char c = cvWaitKey(33);

        if(c==27) 
         {
            //cleaning up
            cvDestroyAllWindows(); 
            cvReleaseImage(&frame);
            cvReleaseImage(&imgGrayScale);
            cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
                break;
         }

         //for(int i=1;i<100000000/5;i++);
         cvReleaseImage(&imgGrayScale);
         cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);

    }

    return 0;


}

IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* imgHSV){
    IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(Hue_Min,Saturation_Min,Value_Min), cvScalar(Hue_Max,Saturation_Max,Value_Max), imgThresh);
    return imgThresh;

}

double angle( CvPoint* pt1, CvPoint* pt2, CvPoint* pt0 )
{
    double dx1 = pt1->x - pt0->x;
    double dy1 = pt1->y - pt0->y;
    double dx2 = pt2->x - pt0->x;
    double dy2 = pt2->y - pt0->y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023923/shape-detection-in-python-using-opencv/22042006#22042006 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to extract homogenous regions, MSER (maximally stable extremal regions) is known to have worked well, it is widely used in OCR and the images you have shown also seem to have the same properties, homogenous color regions and then letters inside them. There is also an openCV implementation available for it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions