# Detecting a shape inside of a matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

Lets say you have a matrix like the following:

```
var map = 
[
[0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0],
];
```

What methods could be used to determine that there is a square of `1`s inside of the matrix of `0`s? What about multiple squares/rectangles offset to each other (Not overlapping, just potentially side by side)?

I'm sure that methods have already been made for such things, and I would love to learn about them.

Comment: I can help you please specify your real requirement....

Comment: @piyushbarua I'm trying to find the bounds of squares or rectangles in a 2D array. The end result is to map the bounds of squares in the array and translate that to something else like a `canvas`, or HTML `<area>`s.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It is a kind of broad image processing question,

The concept can be named as **`shape numbers`** , **`shape numbering`**, **`object detection`**, **`OCR`** etc....,

You can use **`OpenCV`** library to detect shapes.

Try this question [How to detect simple geometric shapes using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv)

**--EDIT---**

The ultimate numerical solution is using numerical edge detection and line thinning approaches like **`Canny`**, **`Robert Cross`**, **`Prewitt`**, **`Sobel`** operators and **`kernel`**, **`convolution matrix`** methodologies will help you.

All the above operators can be executed in software like **Matlab**, **OpenCV** .... etc

For JavaScript you can try using the following libraries

**FabricJS** http://fabricjs.com/

**Orcad** http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html

**Shape-Detector** https://github.com/MathieuLoutre/shape-detector

A neural network library

**Brain** https://github.com/harthur/brain

Demo for brain http://katspaugh.github.io/whiteboard/examples/brain/#rect

I think **brain** uses similar 1s and 0s in a matrix which can be more specific to your integer array

Comment: Most image processing I find is of literal images, and is usually very abstracted above this particular problem, not for finding a shape of similar data-points in a 2D array. Are those directly applicable, what should I try and find/look for more specific to this?