# How to find object and angle in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I  have to identify several polygon like shapes.Sometime, shapes have small carves.Anyway, I can extract shape very clearly using shareholding and find contours.

The problem is how to detect a shape exactly that I want? and How to get it's orientation(angle referenced to pre-defined axis)?

Give me your ideas,related links and sample codes.
I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 on Python 2.7.5

Shape may be like this(this has 2 carves,sometime no carves):

[image: Polygon like shape...it has 2 carves]

Comment: Why don't you provide us with some code, we would be more happy to help any issues that you incurred in your code?

Comment: I didn't try to write a code yet.I'm searching for methods that can used for my work.I read some of resources...But,I want to get more..

Comment: Check [convexityDefects](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html)

Comment: What do you mean with predefined axis? How did you define them?

Comment: @PSchn I'm trying to get axis as camera edge (0,0) to (640,480).It's the horizontal axis of video frame.

Comment: And you want to detect if your Polygon is a triangle, pentagon or so? And then calculate the orientation? Can you explain in a bit more?

Comment: @NSiri, this is a classification problem. In order to solve it, you need to train your algorithm with all of the possible classes i.e. triangle,rectangle, circle, polygon, hexagon etc.

Comment: @PSchn I have to place a logo on a detected shape.Logo must be placed to specific position.
I'm trying to make a machine for that.
User load the shape(paper).It can be get any orientation and can be any shape.
For this,I want to detect exact shape and it's orientation. Then I can calculate position for logo printing.

Comment: you could approximate the convexHull and detect your shape by checking the size of the aproximated contour (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv)). Then you need to define your oriantation for each shape.

Comment: any code which you have till now  ??