# Detecting simple geometric shapes using OpenCV [Java]

Tags: java, python, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.1

I'm programming a Java application that detects simple geometric shapes.

The following Python code is used as a reference: [How to detect simple geometric shapes using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11427501/2426320/)

This is some of the code [Python]:

```
contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresholdedImage,1,2)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    print len(approx)
    if len(approx)==5:
        print "pentagon"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,255,-1)
    elif len(approx)==3:
        print "triangle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),-1)
    elif len(approx)==4:
        print "square"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),-1)
    elif len(approx) == 9:
        print "half-circle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(255,255,0),-1)
    elif len(approx) > 15:
        print "circle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,255),-1)
```

Using Java's OpenCV methods, **I'm unable to extract the "len" (length) property** (in order to determine what shape has been detected) of an approximated contour.

Printing out a couple of contours produces [Java]:

```
[ 4*1*CV_32SC2, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x23ac75f0, dataAddr=0x1c7c66c0 ]
[ 5*1*CV_32SC2, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x23ac7200, dataAddr=0x1c0e5fc0 ]
etc.
```

I'd like to get the number of points of a specific contour object -- the `4` and `5` from the code above.

I know I could convert it to a String and then extract the numbers, but there must be a better way, right?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Note that `len` is simply getting the number of elements in the `approx` array. It's not computing `length` of points/lines or anything. It's like a `.length` in Java. So it's just saying "if there's three points its a triangle, five its a pentagon" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. (Assuming you already have `yourImage`stored in a `MatOfPoint2f`object).

```
MatOfPoint2f approx = new MatOfPoint2f();
Imgproc.approxPolyDP(yourImage, approx, Imgproc.arcLength(yourImage, true) * 0.02, true);
long count = approx.total();
if (count == 5) { 
    // this is a pentagon
}
```

Check [this](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#total()) to see the use of `total()`

OpenCV on Java becomes a bit tricky compared with other languages like Python or C++.