# Find all different objects/closed polygons in a room image

Tags: image, opencv

I am a newbie in image processing, I need to find different objects in an image (for example a room image) and be able to distinguish these objects and color them with distinct colors, I started with canny edge detection to find out different edges of the objects but in order to distinguish different objects what do I do next?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect simple geometric shapes using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am not looking for just Geometric shapes , so this would not be the duplicate of the question you specified

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect objects, you should think more than just image processing. The detecting object process is a long process.

Let's start with detecting that is an image a [hotdog or not hotdog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACmydtFDTGs)? Let me summarize the steps;

1. Set the hotdog image which you want to detect
2. Perform [feature extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction)
3. Read the input image and perform feature extraction on it
4. Perform [feature matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) between input image and hotdog image
5. Use a [Machine Learning Classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) to decide that is hotdog or
   not hotdog

If you want to detect hotdog from an image which contains another objects too (i.e. chair, table, coke and etc.), you should perform sliding window approach to detect hotdog and draw bounding box on it.

The state of the art in object detection is Deep Learning. You can train CNN to interpret images but it requires tons of works to train it. You can use trained neural nets, for example [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models)'s trained neural nets, here is a [demo  video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zZe27JYi8Y) about it. You can use it to detect any different kind of object which are in your room image.