# Trying to fill color on square-like object using OpenCV and Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am trying to fill color to that square objects. It does not look like a perfect square. I have attached 4 sample images. Please have a look at it. Please help me with your ideas.

By using this code I can change the background and line colors. But I want to fill color that unshaped squares (squares only not triangle).

```
System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
String img_url1 = "C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\Desktop\\\\cpt\\\\1.png";
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(img_url1, -1);

List<Mat> channels = new ArrayList<>();
Core.split(img, channels);

Mat black = new Mat();
Core.bitwise_not(channels.get(3), black);

String file2 = "C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\me\\\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\\\cpt\\\\\\\\1-cpy.png"; 
Imgcodecs.imwrite(file2, black);
```

Input Images :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What result do you obtain with your code?
If i understand you correctly, that are only the inputs images.

Comment: Yes these are input images

Comment: I don't know where to start with.. looking for some idea

Comment: And you only want to fill the rectangles, not the triangles?

Comment: Yes I want to fill rectangles only

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11427501/2286337).

Comment: I checked but that is something about regular shape right? But in my case it is irregular