# Remove circles from technical drawing image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, ocr, image-manipulation

When OCRing technical drawing, most (all?) ocr engines have problems with surrounding geometry and sometimes falsely interpret a line as letter.

To improve the quality of the OCR, I first want to remove certain elements from the drawing, mainly circles and rectangels, from the image.

The drawings are all black & white and look very similar to the below example.

What is the best way to achieve this? I've played around with image magick and opencv with little success...

[image: tech drawing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a partial solution. This problem can be broken up into two steps:

**1) Remove rectangles by removing horizontal + vertical lines**

We create vertical and horizontal kernels then perform morph close to detect the lines. From here we use bitwise operations to remove the lines.

Detected vertical lines (left) and horizontal lines (right)

[image]
[image]

Removed lines

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,15))
remove_vertical = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, vertical_kernel)

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,1))
remove_horizontal = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel)

result = cv2.add(cv2.add(remove_vertical, remove_horizontal), image)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**2) Detect/remove circles**

There are several approaches to remove the circles

1. Use [`cv2.HoughCircles()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html). Here's a good tutorial to [detect circles in images using Hough Circles](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/)
2. Construct a `cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE` kernel using [`cv2.getStructuringElement()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) then perform [morphological operations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to isolate the circle contours
3. Use simple shape detection with contour approximation and contour filtering to detect the circles. This method uses `cv2.arcLength()` and `cv2.approxPolyDP()` for contour approximation. One tradeoff with this method is that it only works with "perfect" shapes. Take a look at [detect simple geometric shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv) and [opencv shape detection](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/)