# Python OpenCV Detect Width and Height of Contour Shape Vertices

Tags: python, opencv

We are using Python OpenCV to detect shapes. I am using code here to detect shapes.
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

How do I find the width height of the Rectangle below? I could find the greatest subtraction differential between x-values, and greatest-differential of y-values,  by looking at all combinations of vertices below. Curious if Python OpenCV library has a more efficient way to conduct this.
This algorithm could be more cumbersome, if dealing with Pentagons or Hexagons, or shapes with many vertices contours.

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

for contourItem in cnts:

    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 3:
        shape = "triangle"

    elif len(approx) == 4:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        ar = w / float(h)
        shape = "square" if ar >= 0.95 and ar <= 1.05 else "rectangle"

    elif len(approx) == 5:
        shape = "pentagon"
```

**Results of Vertices:**

```
1 = 
 xLocation = 341
 yLocation = 372
2 = 
 xLocation = 277
 yLocation = 410
3 = 
 xLocation = 348
 yLocation = 529
4 = {
 xLocation = 412
 yLocation = 493
```

[Shape Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3JmJ.png)

Resources: [How to detect simple geometric shapes using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv)

Comment: `x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect()` , here w,h gives the rectangle width and height. [Check out](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

Comment: hi @DragonsCanDance feel free to place comment in answer, and I can send points, thanks

Comment: hey, that's perfectly fine. As long as the comment helps you, it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect()` as comment above stated or one can also use `cv2.minAreaRect()`.

> 7.a. Straight Bounding Rectangle It is a straight rectangle, it doesn’t consider the rotation of the object. So area of the bounding
> rectangle won’t be minimum. It is found by the function
> cv2.boundingRect().
>
> Let (x,y) be the top-left coordinate of the rectangle and (w,h) be its
> width and height.

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) 
img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```

> 7.b. Rotated Rectangle Here, bounding rectangle is drawn with minimum area, so it considers the rotation also. The function used is
> cv2.minAreaRect(). It returns a Box2D structure which contains
> following detals - ( top-left corner(x,y), (width, height), angle of
> rotation ). But to draw this rectangle, we need 4 corners of the
> rectangle. It is obtained by the function cv2.boxPoints()

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt) 
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect) 
box = np.int0(box)
im = cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

[Rectangle Image Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY7vB.png)

Thanks also to DragonsCanDance user

From Resource: [Python resource](http://%20https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html)